# Javascript calculated field disappearing when being submitted to mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a Client Data Entry Form, it is quite large but works great. Except for one problem I added a script to calculate the total of up to 5 fields Max. The script works, it does the calculation and the total appears. When I submit the form the data isn't being submitted to mysql.

Here is the script:

```
<script>
var calculateForm = function () {
document.getElementById("total_paid").value = (Number(document.getElementById("amount1").value) + Number(document.getElementById("amount2").value) + Number(document.getElementById("amount3").value) + Number(document.getElementById("amount4").value) + Number(document.getElementById("amount5").value));
};
</script>
```

Here is part of the form:

```
<div class="rent_own_info">
<fieldset name="rent_own">
<legend>Rent / Own</legend>
<table><tbody>
<tr>
<td>Address</td>
<td>Postal Code</td>
<td>Months</td>
<td>Amount</td>
<td>Landlord / Township</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="address1" id="address1"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="pcode1" id="pcode1"  size="10"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="months1" id="months1" size="10"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="amount1" id="amount1" value="" onblur="calculateForm();" size="10"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="paid1" id="paid1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="address2" id="address2"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="pcode2" id="pcode2" size="10"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="months2" id="months2" size="10"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="amount2" id="amount2" value="" onblur="calculateForm();" size="10"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="paid2" id="paid2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="address3" id="address3"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="pcode3" id="pcode3" size="10"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="months3" size="10"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="amount3" id="amount3" value="" onblur="calculateForm();" size="10"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="paid3" id="paid3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="address4" id="address4"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="pcode4" id="pcode4" size="10"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="months4" size="10"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="amount4" id="amount4" value="" onblur="calculateForm();" size="10"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="paid4" id="paid4"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="address5" id="address5"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="pcode5" id="pcode5" size="10"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="months5" size="10"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="amount5" id="amount5" value="" onblur="calculateForm();" size="10"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="paid5" id="paid5"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" name="" id=""></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="" id="" size="10"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="" size="10" value="Total Paid"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="total_paid" id="total_paid" value="" size="10"></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="" id=""></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

I have checked the apache2 and the mysql logs and no errors.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanx ZZ

Comment: Sounds like the calculation function is running after the submission takes place. Also, are you sure it's not getting sent? Check the network log to see which parameters are being sent, or ask PHP (via `var_ump($_POST)`) what it's receiving.

Comment: Thank you for the hints Utkanos. Var_dump($_POST) helped... The info was there.